# MVC: Pagination hindering the way a list is sorted

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagination

I am building an MVC-App and I am looking for an efficient way to do paging in my view.

So far I have installed the [following](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/paging-sorting-in-mvc-4/) paging system. However, if this paging system does work well, it has a flaw: the list shown in the view is not the full list, but rather what portion of the list the user is viewing based on the page number. The flaw being that if I use a jQuery system to sort the items, it will only sort the items in the current page, and not the total list.

Allow me to demonstrate my meaning. Say that I have this view:

```
@using MyApp.Models
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyApp.Utilities.CardDisplay>

<h2>
    Cards Display Results
</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cardRarity').change(function () {
            var showCardRarity = $(this).val();
            if (showCardRarity == "All") {
                $(".cardRarity").show();
            } else {
                $(".cardRarity").hide();
                $(".cardRarity-" + showCardRarity).each(function() {
                    $(this).show();
                });
            }
        });
        $('#cardType').change(function() {
            var showCardType = $(this).val();
            if (showCardType == "All") {
                $(".cardType").show();
            } else {
                $(".cardType").hide();
                $(".cardType-" + showCardType).each(function() {
                    $(this).show();
                });
            }
        });
        $('#cardColor').change(function() {
            var showCardColor = $(this).val();
            if (showCardColor == "All") {
                $(".cardColor").show();
            } else {
                $(".cardColor").hide();
                $(".cardColor-" + showCardColor).each(function() {
                    $(this).show();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Filter by rarity: <select name="cardRarity" id="cardRarity" tabindex="1">
                             <option value="All">All</option>
                             <option value="Land">Land</option>
                             <option value="Common">Common</option>
                             <option value="Uncommon">Uncommon</option>
                             <option value="Rare">Rare</option>
                             <option value="Mythic Rare">Mythic Rare</option>
                             <option value="Special">Special</option>
                         </select>
        Filter by type: <select name="cardType" id="cardType" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            <option value="Artifact">Artifact</option>
                            <option value="Instant">Instant</option>
                            <option value="Creature">Creature</option>
                            <option value="Land">Land</option>
                            <option value="Planeswalker">Planeswalker</option>
                            <option value="Enchantment">Enchantment</option>
                            <option value="Sorcery">Sorcery</option>
                            <option value="Tribal">Tribal</option>
                        </select>
        Filter by color: <select name="cardColor" id="cardColor" tabindex="3">
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            <option value="White">White</option>
                            <option value="Red">Red</option>
                            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                            <option value="Green">Green</option>
                            <option value="Black">Black</option>
                            <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                            <option value="Colorless">Colorless</option>
                        </select>
    </p>
}
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    if (Model.PageCount > 1)
    {
        <div class="center">
            Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
            of @Model.PageCount

            @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("<<", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber - 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
            }
            else
            {
                @:<<
                @Html.Raw(" ");
                @:< Prev
            }

            @if (Model.HasNextPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber + 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink(">>", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageCount, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
            }
            else
            {
                @:Next >
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @:>>
            }
        </div>
    }
    <table id="resultTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Item number</th>
            <th>Card Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Mana Cost</th>
            <th>Mana Converted</th>
            <th>Card Type</th>
            <th>Power</th>
            <th>Toughness</th>
            <th>Rarity</th>
            <th>Card Set</th>
            <th>Artist Name </th>
            <th>Actions </th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            var className = i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";

            var row = ((i + 1) + ((Model.PageNumber - 1) * 50));

            <tr class="@className cardRarity cardRarity-@(Model[i].mCardRarity.Replace(" ", "-")) 
                cardType cardType-@(Model[i].mStrippedCardType)
                cardColor cardColor-@(Model[i].mCardColor)">
                <td>@row</td>
                <td class="center">
                    @(Model[i].mCardFlagFace == CardInfo.FlagFaceValue.Normal ?
                    Html.ActionLink(Model[i].mCardName, "CardDetails", new {_cardId = Model[i].mCardID}) :
                    Html.ActionLink(Model[i].mCardName + " // " + Model[i].mChildCard.mCardName, "CardDetails", new {_cardId = Model[i].mCardID}))
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardColor)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardManaCost)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardManaConverted)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardPower)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardToughness)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardRarity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardSet.mCardSetName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardArtistName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {@_cardId = Model[i].mCardID})
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {@_cardId = Model[i].mCardID})
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {@_cardId = Model[i].mCardID})
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    if (Model.PageCount > 1)
    {
        <div class="center">
            Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
            of @Model.PageCount

            @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("<<", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber - 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
            }
            else
            {
                @:<<
                @Html.Raw(" ");
                @:< Prev
            }

            @if (Model.HasNextPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber + 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink(">>", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageCount, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort })
            }
            else
            {
                @:Next >
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @:>>
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Say that I have a list of 50 cards to display, but the page number of cards allowed is 20. Based on this view, if I change the selected option `Card Type` to `Creature`, the view will indeed sort and display all the creatures, but **only for the 20 cards displayed and not for the whole list**.

That is why I need help: I need to figure a way either to either load the entire list to the view, and then sort out some paging way, or to redisplay only the wanted item, and I'd love to do it without having to rewrite my controller method, though I do not mind adding new features. I've heard that JSon might help, but I don't know how it works. Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT**

Here's the working code!

First, I have modified the javascript function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cardRarity').change(function () {
            var showCardRarity = $(this).val();
            refreshResults(($(this).attr("id")), showCardRarity);
        });
        $('#cardType').change(function () {
            alert("Type changed");
            var showCardType = $(this).val();
            refreshResults(($(this).attr("id")), showCardType);
        });
        $('#cardColor').change(function () {
            alert("Color changed");
            var showCardColor = $(this).val();
            refreshResults(($(this).attr("id")), showCardColor);
        });

        function refreshResults(filter, value) {
            alert(filter);
            $.get("@Url.Action("DisplayCardsResults", "Card")", {
                _page: 1,
                _sortOrder: "@ViewBag._sortOrder",
                _filter: filter,
                _searchValue: value
            }, function(data) {
                $("#resultTable").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The `function refreshResults` was a bit tricky because I had to figure how to call a controller method from a javascript function and pass data through it. I love stackOverflow!

Then I removed everything beyond the `@if(Model.Count > 0)` and put that in a partial view that I was calling like this:

```
<div id="resultsDiv">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_ResultsTable", @Model);
    }
</div>
```

And then, in my controller, I had to sort things through:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCardsResults(int? _page, string _sortOrder, string _filter = "", string _searchValue = "")
{
    ViewBag._searchValue = _searchValue;
    ViewBag._filter = _filter;

    if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
    {
        _page = 1;
    }

    int pageNumber = (_page ?? 1);

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        switch (_filter)
        {

            // The mListCardsToShow is an inner list I keep and it is different from the mListCards because of the where clause which flush the rest of the data.

            case "cardRarity":
                if (_searchValue == "All")
                {
                    mListCardsToShow = mListCards.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    mListCardsToShow.AddRange(mListCards.Where(_item => _item.mMasterCard.mCardRarity == _searchValue));
                }
                break;
            case "cardType":
                if (_searchValue == "All")
                {
                    mListCardsToShow = mListCards.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    mListCardsToShow.AddRange(mListCards.Where(_item => _item.mMasterCard.mCardType == _searchValue));
                }
                break;
            case "cardColor":
                if (_searchValue == "All")
                {
                    mListCardsToShow = mListCards.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    mListCardsToShow.AddRange(mListCards.Where(_item => _item.mMasterCard.mCardColor == _searchValue));
                }
                break;
            default:
                mListCardsToShow = mListCards.ToList();
                break;
        }

        return PartialView("_ResultsTable", mListCardsToShow.ToPagedList(pageNumber, ValueDomain.PAGE_SIZE));
    }

    return View(mListCards.ToPagedList(pageNumber, ValueDomain.PAGE_SIZE));
}
```

Now, I must admit that the sorting is not perfect, like, I would need to take in account each three of the filter, but that's another story. Things works, and I'm happy for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for Tyler. AJAX is the only elegant way I can think of. You have to submit the page to the server every time a drop down is changed and you will get the data but the thing your page refreshes every time without AJAX.

**EDIT:**

This is how you do it using ajax.

This is your view

```
@using MyApp.Models
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyApp.Utilities.CardDisplay>

<h2>
    Cards Display Results
</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cardRarity').change(function () {
            var showCardRarity = $(this).val();
            refreshResults(($(this).attr("id")),showCardRarity );
        });
        $('#cardType').change(function() {
            var showCardType = $(this).val();
            refreshResults(($(this).attr("id")),showCardRarity );
        });
        $('#cardColor').change(function() {
            var showCardColor = $(this).val();
            refreshResults(($(this).attr("id")),showCardRarity );
        });

        function refreshResults(filter, value){
          $.get("YourController/DisplayCardsResults", 
            { 
                _page = 1,   
                _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort,
                _filter = filter,
                _searchValue =  value 
            },
            function (data{
              $("#resultsDiv").html(data);
            }
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Filter by rarity: <select name="cardRarity" id="cardRarity" tabindex="1">
                             <option value="All">All</option>
                             <option value="Land">Land</option>
                             <option value="Common">Common</option>
                             <option value="Uncommon">Uncommon</option>
                             <option value="Rare">Rare</option>
                             <option value="Mythic Rare">Mythic Rare</option>
                             <option value="Special">Special</option>
                         </select>
        Filter by type: <select name="cardType" id="cardType" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            <option value="Artifact">Artifact</option>
                            <option value="Instant">Instant</option>
                            <option value="Creature">Creature</option>
                            <option value="Land">Land</option>
                            <option value="Planeswalker">Planeswalker</option>
                            <option value="Enchantment">Enchantment</option>
                            <option value="Sorcery">Sorcery</option>
                            <option value="Tribal">Tribal</option>
                        </select>
        Filter by color: <select name="cardColor" id="cardColor" tabindex="3">
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            <option value="White">White</option>
                            <option value="Red">Red</option>
                            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                            <option value="Green">Green</option>
                            <option value="Black">Black</option>
                            <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                            <option value="Colorless">Colorless</option>
                        </select>
    </p>
}

<div id="resultsDiv">
    @Html.RenderPartial("_ResultsTable",@Model)
<div>
```

Put this in partial view _ResultsTable

```
@using MyApp.Models
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyApp.Utilities.CardDisplay>

@if (Model.Count > 0)
    {
        if (Model.PageCount > 1)
        {
            <div class="center">
                Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
                of @Model.PageCount

            @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("<<", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber - 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
            }
            else
            {
                @:<<
                @Html.Raw(" ");
                @:< Prev
            }

            @if (Model.HasNextPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber + 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink(">>", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageCount, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
            }
            else
            {
                @:Next >
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @:>>
            }
        </div>
    }
    <table id="resultTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Item number</th>
            <th>Card Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Mana Cost</th>
            <th>Mana Converted</th>
            <th>Card Type</th>
            <th>Power</th>
            <th>Toughness</th>
            <th>Rarity</th>
            <th>Card Set</th>
            <th>Artist Name </th>
            <th>Actions </th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            var className = i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";

            var row = ((i + 1) + ((Model.PageNumber - 1) * 50));

            <tr class="@className cardRarity cardRarity-@(Model[i].mCardRarity.Replace(" ", "-")) 
                cardType cardType-@(Model[i].mStrippedCardType)
                cardColor cardColor-@(Model[i].mCardColor)">
                <td>@row</td>
                <td class="center">
                    @(Model[i].mCardFlagFace == CardInfo.FlagFaceValue.Normal ?
                    Html.ActionLink(Model[i].mCardName, "CardDetails", new {_cardId = Model[i].mCardID}) :
                    Html.ActionLink(Model[i].mCardName + " // " + Model[i].mChildCard.mCardName, "CardDetails", new {_cardId = Model[i].mCardID}))
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardColor)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardManaCost)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardManaConverted)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardPower)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardToughness)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardRarity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardSet.mCardSetName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].mCardArtistName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {@_cardId = Model[i].mCardID})
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {@_cardId = Model[i].mCardID})
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {@_cardId = Model[i].mCardID})
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    if (Model.PageCount > 1)
    {
        <div class="center">
            Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
            of @Model.PageCount

            @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("<<", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber - 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
            }
            else
            {
                @:<<
                @Html.Raw(" ");
                @:< Prev
            }

            @if (Model.HasNextPage)
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageNumber + 1, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @Html.ActionLink(">>", "DisplayCardsResults", new { _page = Model.PageCount, _sortOrder = ViewBag._currentSort, _filter = ViewBag._filter, _searchValue = ViewBag._searchValue })
            }
            else
            {
                @:Next >
                @Html.Raw(" ")
                @:>>
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

In the controller do this:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCardsResults(int _page, string _sortOrder, string _filter = "", string _searchValue = "")
{
  ViewBag._filter = _filter;
  ViewBag._searchValue= _searchValue;

  //Do whatever you are doing to get the cards but to the resultant collection add the following where condition, suppose the collection is in var cards


 switch (_filter)
            {
                case "cardRarity":
                    cards = cards.Where(s => s.CardRarity == _searchValue);
                    break;
                case "cardType":
                    cards = cards.Where(s => s.CardType == _searchValue);
                    break;
                case "cardColor":
                    cards = cards.Where(s => s.CardColor == _searchValue);
                    break;
                default:
                    // no filter
                    break;
            }
   if(Request.isAjaxRequest)
      return PartialView("_ResultsTable",cards);
  return View(cards);
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I do think that this would be an interesting idea, but I have no clues as to how to do this because I do not know AJAX lest of its existence... :S

Comment: I added one of doing it with AJAX in my edit, but you may want to a progress bar when the page is loading so that the user will know the table is being refreshed.

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to make me do, and I appreciate it. Only problem tho is that the javascript you included contains much errors and cannot be written that way. I'm working out to make it work, so if you don't mind checking it out, that would be great. :)

Comment: As for the progress bar, that's also something I need to do, but don't know HOW to do.

Comment: It's the function refreshResults that does not seems right. Many errors are popping in my view.

Comment: Can you tell me what errors you are getting so that I can look into it.

Comment: You code helped me a lot, almost there. I've tweaked it a little bit, and I'm working hard on it, so as soon as I get stuck, or finally get a result, I'll post it back, and award you the answer.

Comment: Tadah! Worked! I will post the full code ahead so you'll know how I fixed your javascript function :)

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes the thing is I didn't include double quotes and also `@` which will result in an error, thanks for pointing that out. As far as I know, `$.get('Card/DisplayCardsResults'` should also work.

Comment: Yeah, but by using the `@Url.Action` command I can safely bind the controller method I wish to target with the Ajax call, which is more safe ;) Thanks still!

Comment: Okay. I am glad you are able to figure it out

Answer (score 3):

This certainly sounds like something where AJAX would help solve your problem and make things more elegant - it would be worth doing some research on. Right now whenever a user clicks one of the links, it requires a full page reload to simply get the next page worth of data in the table. You can instead dynamically update just the table when you need to.

Check out the documentation for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - in the URL you pass to the server you could set the filters (pagination and sorting), and in the success handler you would update the values in your table. Also don't be intimidated by the term JSON, that is just a term for data storage primarily used by js, you could set up an action on your controller which would return the information in JSON which gets processed in the AJAX success handler.

PS: Yay MtG, good luck :)

Comment: I'd like to try something out with Ajax! But I am not sure how I could do this.

Answer (score 2):

Loading the entire list is usually not a good idea if you have a lot of values. In your case though 50 records are not much but generally is not an efficient design to follow.
Have a look at the following articles.

http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/GridDemo/CustomQuerying

http://kevww.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/how-to-implement-paging-sorting-in-mvc-3-part-2-how-to-use-it-for-paging-sorting/

https://web.archive.org/web/20210306164725/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012611-1.aspx

Also Mvc has a WebGrid out of the box that is usually good for this type of scenarios.
May be will suit your needs.

http://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/efficient-paging-and-sorting-with-webgrid-web-helper-asp-net-mvc/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Hope it helps.